# Copying fields from one attribute table to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have two layers. One is point, the other one a line. They both share same x and y coordinate. How do I transfer one field from the point layer to another field in the line layer based on the same coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`?

Comment: Yes but that creates another layer, and I need the specific field in the line layer attribute table. It is about an address. I need the line layer attribute table as It is just need to put the address field from the point layer to the address one. This way with join attributes by location it creates another layer that consists of points.

Comment: Then add a `link/join` in the line layers properties.

Comment: Point and line must have different geometries - do you mean that one or more of the points intersects each line? Some examples of the data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

Use this expression in field calculator of your lines layer:

```
geomintersects('nameofpointlayer','fieldnameyouwanttojoin')
```

Important note: This will only work properly if only one point intersects, otherwise it will only grab the first intersecting one!

[image]

Comment: didn't work, in the expression itself says 'null'

Comment: Then they dont share the same coordinate. You could try using a buffer.

Comment: how do I do that. I am new to Qgis, sorry

Comment: search for `buffer` in your `processing toolbox`. you might also want to take a look at https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html. if you have further questions about this and your original question, i recommend to open up a new question, which includes all these details.